# How do I make a query that selects where the SUM equals a fixed value

Tags: sql, db2

I've spent that last couple of days searching for a way to make a SQL query that searches the database and returns records where the SUM of the same ID's equal or grater then the value provided.

For this I've been using the W3schools database to test it out in the [products table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_sum).

More so what I've been trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE supplierid=? and SUM(price) > 50
```

in the "where supplier id" would loop through same suppliers and sum of their price higher than 50 in this case return the records.

In this case it would read supplier ID 1 then add the price of all that supplier 18+19+10=47 now 47 < 50 so it will not print those records at the end. Next supplier ID 2 22+21.35=43.35 and again would not print those records until the sum of price is higher than 50 it will print

I'm working with a DB2 database.
SAMPLE data:

```
ProductID   ProductName SupplierID  CategoryID  Price
1           Chais       1           1           18
2           Chang       1           1           19
3           Aniseed     1           2           10
4           Chef Anton  2           2           22
5           Chef Anton  2           2           21.35
6           Grandma's   3           2           25
7           Uncle Bob   3           7           30
8           Northwoods  3           2           40
9           Mishi       4           6           97
10          Ikura       4           8           31
11          Queso       5           4           21
12          Queso       5           4           38
13          Konbu       6           8           6
14          Tofu        6           7           23.25
```

Comment: GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: If you use `SUM()` on some columns only you need to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
select * from products where supplierid in (
  select supplierid
    from products
    group by supplierid
    having sum(price) > 50
);
```

The subquery finds out all the `supplierid` values that match your condition. The main (external) query retrieves all rows that match the list of `supplierid`s.

Answer (score 2):

not tested, but I would expect db2 to have analytic functions and CTEs, so perhaps:

```
with
basedata as (
select t.*
     , sum(t.price) over(partition by t.supplierid) sum_price
  from products t
)
select * 
  from basedata
 where supplierid = ?
   and sum_price > 50
```

The analytic function aggregates the price information but does not group the resultset, so you get the rows from your initial result, but restricted to those with an aggregated price value > 50.

The difference to a solution with a subquery is, that the use of the analytic function should be more efficient since it has to read the table only once to produce the result.

Comment: This is the better solution.